# Is direct speech an object of a verb?

Tags: reported-speech

> I said that I played soccer.

“That I player soccer” is an object of a verb.”

> I said, “I played soccer.”

Is “‘I played soccer’” an object of a verb?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, “I played soccer” is a direct quotation and is the direct object of the verb “said.”

Here is a link to sentence diagramming of direct quotations.
https://www.english-grammar-revolution.com/direct-speech.html